# Artemis client-side load balancing on two standalone broker

Tags: apache-camel, jms, activemq-artemis

I have two standalone Artemis 2.14.0 broker instance running (NOT clustered)
Lets say one instance is running in host1 and another in host2.

I am using a camel 2.20 with connectionFactory url as `tcp://host1:61616?...` and able to consume messages from only that instance.

If I wanted to consume messages from both the standalone broker instance with client side load balancing will the below connectionfactory URL configuration work ?

```
(tcp://host1:61616,tcp://host2:61616)?reconnectAttempts=5;useTopologyForLoadBalancing=false
```

I haven't tried this config, since from the [documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/clusters.html#client-side-load-balancing) the statement seems to support it:

- Specifying servers explicitly in the URL. This also requires setting the `useTopologyForLoadBalancing` parameter to `false` on the URL.

---

****UPDATED****
[Relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67222394/camel-jms-artemis-client-with-two-standalone-broker-configuration-url-is-consumi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client-side connection load-balancing works behind the scenes so that as multiple connections are created from the same `ConnectionFactory` instance they are balanced between the brokers according to the specified load-balancing policy (round-robin by default). Since you aren't actually clustering then you should definitely set `useTopologyForLoadBalancing=false`.

Comment: When i use camel to with both host configured, the client is only connecting to one host. (updated the details within the same question with more details after title UPDATED)

Comment: I think you probably need to create a new question with this updated information.