# Camel JMS Artemis client with two standalone broker configuration url is consuming message from only one host

Tags: apache-camel, spring-jms, activemq-artemis

I have started two standalone Artemis broker in my localhost with `61616` and `61617` port for checking.

Ideally I want to connect to two standalone Artemis broker running in different host within same network. The broker is not configured in Cluster.

Below is the Camel configuration i am trying to use.

With the Artemis 2.14.0 client jar I noticed that consumer is connected to only to one host (`61616`) and started consuming message. I don't see any consumer to `localhost:61617`.

Is anything incorrect with the below configuration.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee" 
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring
        http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

      <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQJMSConnectionFactory">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="(tcp://localhost:61616,tcp://localhost:61617)?useTopologyLoadBalancing=false;wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=500000"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsPooledConnectionFactory" class="org.messaginghub.pooled.jms.JmsPoolConnectionFactory" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
      <property name="maxConnections" value="10" />
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jmsConfig" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration">
      <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsPooledConnectionFactory" />
      <property name="concurrentConsumers" value="10" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="jms" class="org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsComponent">
      <property name="configuration" ref="jmsConfig" />
      <property name="streamMessageTypeEnabled" value="true"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="SimplePrintBean" class="com.test.SimplePrint" scope="prototype" />
    <camelContext id="camel" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">

       <endpoint id="sampleQueue" uri="jms:queue:${queueName}" />

      <route>
        <from uri="ref:sampleQueue" />
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
        <transform>
          <simple>MSG TO QUEUE : ${bodyAs(String)}</simple>
        </transform>
        <bean ref="SimplePrintBean" method="print"/>
      </route>
    </camelContext>
    
  </beans>
```

I eventually tried below which also didn't work

```
(tcp://localhost:61616?useTopologyLoadBalancing=false,tcp://localhost:61617?useTopologyLoadBalancing=false;)?wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=500000
```

without `useTopologyLoadBalancing=false`, the same behavior too.

Broker.xml - same configuration only the `<acceptor>` url was updated with 61617 on the other broker.

```xml
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
               xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq /schema/artemis-configuration.xsd">

   <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="urn:activemq:core ">

      <name>0.0.0.0</name>
      <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
      <journal-type>ASYNCIO</journal-type>
      <paging-directory>data/paging</paging-directory>
      <bindings-directory>data/bindings</bindings-directory>
      <journal-directory>data/journal</journal-directory>
      <large-messages-directory>data/large-messages</large-messages-directory>
      <journal-datasync>true</journal-datasync>
      <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>
      <journal-pool-files>10</journal-pool-files>
      <journal-device-block-size>4096</journal-device-block-size>
      <journal-file-size>10M</journal-file-size>
      <journal-buffer-timeout>2220000</journal-buffer-timeout>
      <journal-max-io>4096</journal-max-io>
      <disk-scan-period>5000</disk-scan-period>
      <max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>
      <critical-analyzer>true</critical-analyzer>
      <critical-analyzer-timeout>120000</critical-analyzer-timeout>
      <critical-analyzer-check-period>60000</critical-analyzer-check-period>
      <critical-analyzer-policy>HALT</critical-analyzer-policy>
      <page-sync-timeout>20620000</page-sync-timeout>
      <acceptors>
         <acceptor name="artemis">tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;protocols=CORE,AMQP,STOMP,HORNETQ,MQTT,OPENWIRE;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;amqpDuplicateDetection=true;supportAdvisory=false</acceptor>
         <acceptor name="amqp">tcp://0.0.0.0:5672?tcpSendBufferSize=1048576;tcpReceiveBufferSize=1048576;protocols=AMQP;useEpoll=true;amqpCredits=1000;amqpLowCredits=300;amqpMinLargeMessageSize=102400;amqpDuplicateDetection=true</acceptor>
      </acceptors>

      <security-settings>
         <security-setting match="#">
            <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteDurableQueue" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="createAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="deleteAddress" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="consume" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="browse" roles="amq"/>
            <permission type="send" roles="amq"/>
            <!-- we need this otherwise ./artemis data imp wouldn't work -->
            <permission type="manage" roles="amq"/>
         </security-setting>
      </security-settings>

      <address-settings>
         <!-- if you define auto-create on certain queues, management has to be auto-create -->
         <address-setting match="activemq.management#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
         <!--default for catch all-->
         <address-setting match="#">
            <dead-letter-address>DLQ</dead-letter-address>
            <expiry-address>ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
            <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
            <!-- with -1 only the global-max-size is in use for limiting -->
            <max-size-bytes>-1</max-size-bytes>
            <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
            <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
            <auto-create-queues>true</auto-create-queues>
            <auto-create-addresses>true</auto-create-addresses>
            <auto-create-jms-queues>true</auto-create-jms-queues>
            <auto-create-jms-topics>true</auto-create-jms-topics>
         </address-setting>
      </address-settings>

      <addresses>
         <address name="DLQ">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="DLQ" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
         <address name="ExpiryQueue">
            <anycast>
               <queue name="ExpiryQueue" />
            </anycast>
         </address>
      </addresses>
   </core>
</configuration>
```

Comment: A lot of how this works is going to come down to how Camel is written. How many connections is Camel creating? Is Camel using the same `ConnectionFactory` instance to create each connection? How does the `concurrentConsumers` configuration relate to the underlying JMS connections (e.g. does a value of `10` result in 10 connections being created)?

Comment: Why aren't you clustering? You almost certainly will want to cluster your brokers together to avoid consumer starvation issues. Also, keep in mind that if you only have a few clients you won't need to cluster at all. A single ActiveMQ Artemis broker can deal with thousands of clients and millions of messages per second in some use-cases.

Comment: Probably that would be the next option i need to do, i do have other set of broker which connected in cluster acts like (master- backup).